# How to synchronise web application database with a windows application database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am having two databases for  the same application , one in windows and the other is web based.Since web based one have  few functionalities I can't opt for a single database.At the same time I want to share Both databases to be updated with other's data so as to work error free with my module of appointment fixing.If anyone have a nice solution to this problem please help me with your advise,Thanks.......

Comment: You need to clarify your question.  What are you looking for?  Is the "windows" db hosted on user desktops or on a central server?  Is the "web based" db hosted on a server in the same facility or off site?  How will users be accessing the web interface?  The "windows" db?

Comment: windows db is on a central server.Web db is hosted on a offsite server.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify the statement, "Since web based one have few functionalities"? The best option is to use one database for both apps.

Edit:

If the web db only has a minimal set of tables, it should be easy to roll that schema into the other database and then host onh the offsite server. Problem solved...

Comment: It means web based db is only a small part of the other(only meant for appointment module)

Answer (score 0):

Go for a single database no matter how much wrangling it takes. Two way DB synchronization is not for the faint of heart and I find it hard to believe that you can't find a way to use a single DB.

Even if one of the databases is not feature rich enough ("have few functionalities") use the OTHER one as your single DB.

UPDATE: Here's another thought. It is not unheard of for an application to access two separate databases to do its job. Why not keep both and have the apps query whichever is needed?

Comment: That's nice,but my DBs are in different servers and are at different places.so even if I use a single database how could I update it in each server.

Comment: If you had a DB in a single place you wouldn't NEED to update it on each server. That's kind of my point.